# Determine if files with a certain file extension are not in the folder using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a folder that does not contain any files with the extension "rar". I run the following from the PowerShell commandline using gci (alias of [Get-ChildItem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)):

```
PS> gci *.rar
```

As expected, nothing is reported back since no such files exist. But when I do an `"echo $?"`, it returns true.

How can I test the non-existence of files for a given file extension? I am using PowerShell v2 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#If no rar files found...
if (!(gci c:\ *.rar)){
    "No rar files!"
}
#If rar files found...
if (gci c:\ *.rar){
    "Found rar file(s)!"
}
```

'if' evaluates the condition specified between the parentheses, this returns a boolean (True or False), the code between the curly braces executes if the condition returns true.  In this instance if gci returns 0 files that would return False (perhaps equivalent to 'if exists') so in the first example we use the *not* operator (!) to essentially inverse the logic to return a True and execute the code block.  In the second example we're looking for the existence of rar files and want the code block to execute if it finds any.

Comment: +1 This works.  Can you explain how the if statement gets the result from the gci cmdlet?  Thank you.

Comment: @Lars Thanks, like your answer too, good additional information - was surprised the V3 syntax was a no go in V2!

Answer (score 3):

gci returns an array. You can check how many results are in the array.

```
if ((gci *.rar | measure-object).count -eq 0)
{
  "No rars"
}
```

With PowerShell v3 it's a bit easier:

```
if ((gci *.rar).Count -eq 0)
{
  "No rars"
}
```

Comment: +1 Yes, this works.  Did not know about measure-object, thanks.